# Pass different values from one component to another depending on a condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To one of the headers in the table, I added functionality that will be responsible for sorting this column. The code looks like this:

```
    export default function TableHeader() {
    const [isSorted, setIsSorted] = useState(false)
    return (
        <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell >Device</TableCell>
                <TableCell >Last
                    <div onClick={() => setIsSorted(!isSorted)}>
                        {isSorted
                        ? <SwapVertIcon  />
                        : <SwapVertIcon  />
                        }
                    </div>
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
    );
}
```

However, in order for the data to be sorted when the icon is clicked (and not just the effect of the moving icon), I need to somehow pass the data to the component where the table itself is formed (that is, the parent component). So that the logic would be something like this: if isSorted == false, then the data is sorted in one order (const devices), if isSorted == true, then in another (const devicesSort).

```
 export default function DevicesTable() {
    const devicesSort = useDevices(database, firestore, urlParams, hiddenItems, filters)
            .slice() 
            .sort((a, b) => a.lastPacketTimestamp - b.lastPacketTimestamp)

    return (
        <TableContainer >
            <Table >
                <DevicesTableHeader />
                <TableBody>
                    {devices.map((device) =>
                        <DevicesTableCell device={device}  />)}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
}
```

But I can't figure out how to pass values from one component to another. Perhaps you can tell me

Comment: Multiple solutions possible: [Lift the state up](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-lifting-state-up-in-react/) or pass a callback function as a prop which you define in the parent component and you handle the sorting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different way to achieve this. However the simplest is to move the condition to the parent component. Here's an example

```
export default function DevicesTableHeader({ isSorted, onSortClick }) {

    return (
        <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell align='left' style={styles.TableHeaderStyle}>Device id</TableCell>
                <TableCell align='left' style={styles.TableHeaderStyle}>Last activity
                    <div onClick={onSortClick}>
                        {isSorted
                        ? <SwapVertIcon  />
                        : <SwapVertIcon style={{transform: 'rotateY(180deg)'}} />
                        }
                    </div>
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
    );
}
```

And in parent you can pass the props as a state

```
 export default function DevicesTable() {
    const [isSorted, setIsSorted] = useState(false)

    const { database, firestore, filters } = useContext(AppContext)
    const { hiddenItems, urlParams } = useContext(PageContext)
    const devices = useDevices(database, firestore, urlParams, hiddenItems, filters)

    const devicesSort = useDevices(database, firestore, urlParams, hiddenItems, filters)
            .slice() 
            .sort((a, b) => a.lastPacketTimestamp - b.lastPacketTimestamp)
   const stateBasedDeviceSort = isSorted ? devices : devicesSort
    return (
        <TableContainer style={styles.TableContainerGridStyle}>
            <Table style={styles.TableStyle}>
                <DevicesTableHeader isSorted={isSorted} onSortClick={() => setIsSorted(!isSorted)} />
                <TableBody>
                    {stateBasedDeviceSort.map((device) =>
                        <DevicesTableCell device={device} key={device.description.id} />)}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
}
```

Comment: Its goooood solution. Thank you!